# What is the computational complexity of Romberg Integration?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-complexity

I wrote some code, and I'd like to identify the computational complexity. There is one outer loop and two inner loops.

The outer loop goes from i = 1 to some $n$, where $n$ is the number of times a trapezoid is evenly divided. This division results in $2^n + 1$ evaluation points ($k = 1 \dots 2^n + 1$) in the first inner loop.

The second inner loop depends goes from goes from $j = 1 \dots i$, where $i$ is the current index of the outer loop.

So normally, I believe you look at the number of nested loops and that tells you the order of the complexity. However, in this case there are nested loops with very different stopping values. What technique would I use to figure this out, when the stop values are not uniform?

```
def integrate(func, a, b, steps):
    """
    Uses Romberg Integration to estimate up to best guess R(n, m)

    :param func: The function to integrate
    :param a: start
    :param b: stop
    :param steps: the number of times to divide the interval evenly
    :return: a triangular table of values, where the diagonal contains
    increasing accurate estimates.
    """

    r = np.zeros((steps, steps))
    h = (b - a)
    # Compute Trapezoid Rule estimate:
    r[0, 0] = 0.5*h*(func(a) + func(b))

    # Compute Composite Trap estimates:
    # 2^n is the number of segments
    # N = 2^n + 1 is the number of evaluation points
    # h = (b - a)/2^n is the step size
    for n in range(1, steps):
        h = (b - a) / 2**n

        r[n, 0] = 0.5 * r[n - 1, 0] \
            + h * np.sum(func(a + (2*k - 1)*h)
                         for k in np.arange(1, 2**(n - 1) + 1))

        # Use Richardson extrapolation for higher order accuracy:
        for m in range(1, n + 1):
            r[n, m] = r[n, m - 1] + 1 / (4**m - 1) * (r[n, m - 1] - r[n - 1, m - 1])

    print('The best estimate with convergence order {} and {} parts is {}'.format(steps, 2 ** steps, r[-1, -1]))
    return r
```

Comment: You have the $2^n+1$ function values with $2^n$ additions combining them, and afterwards a triangular scheme with side length $n$, giving $n^2/2$ extrapolation operations. The first is clearly dominant.

Comment: So, in general, you use the loops with the highest number of evaluations to calculate computational complexity? Are you saying that the outer loop does not contribute to that calculation at all?

Comment: Usually the function you integrate is more complex than the identity, so that the repeated function evaluations indeed dominate, $2^{-n}n^2$ is bounded and converges to zero. // I did not read the code carefully. Replace $n$ with `steps` in my comment above, as that gives the final shape of the computational picture. Note that in every step in the outer loop, the effort up to this point resembles the shape of the final effort, a line of $2^n+1$ function evaluations and $n^2/2$ extrapolations, of which $2^{n-1}$ and $n$ are performed during the step.